# How to multi use switch statement?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, switch-statement

I have two scenarios that use the same switch structure.  Rather than creating two switches that are basically duplicates, is there a way to reuse the structure?

First scenario:

```
switch (someString)
{
  case constant1:
   //create class1
   break;
  case constant2:
   //create class2
   break;
  default:
   break;
}
```

Second scenario:

```
switch (someString)
{
  case constant1:
   return true;
  case constant2:
   return true;
  default:
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *could* have:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<Foo>> SomeSensibleName = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<Foo>>
{
    { Constant1, () => new Class1() },
    { Constant2, () => new Class2() },
    ...
};
```

Then in place of the first:

```
Func<Foo> factory;
if (SomeSensibleName.TryGetValue(someString, out factory))
{
    Foo result = factory();
    // Use it, presumably...
}
```

And in place of the second:

```
return SomeSensibleName.ContainsKey(someString);
```

Is that the sort of thing you were looking for?

Comment: yeah.  Nice.  Thanks Jon.

Answer (score 0):

You can think about using delegates to provide an action:

```
bool Switcher(string someString, Func<bool> constant1Action, 
                                 Func<bool> constant2Action, 
                                 Func<bool> defaultAction)
{
    switch (someString)
    {
        case "constant1":
            return constant1Action();
        case "constant2":
            return constant2Action();
        default:
            return defaultAction();
    }
}
```

**BUT** I'm not even sure if it will be more readable than simple switch statements.